# smarty variables within javascript functions

Tags: javascript, smarty

In my cos there are smarty tags
i.g. {$PRODUCTS_PRICE} the value of them is i.g. 1.300,00 EUR

now I want to assign the smarty tag to an array (last row)

```
var google_tag_params = { ;
ecomm_prodid: {/literal}"{$PRODUCTS_ID}"{literal},
ecomm_pagetype: "product",
ecomm_totalvalue:{/literal}{$PRODUCTS_PRICE}{literal}
};
```

this works fine.
But now I want trim the value before assign it to ecomm_totalvalue
I want the value change form 1.300,00 EUR to 1300.00

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [regex_replace](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl) modifier, like so:

```
{$PRODUCTS_PRICE|regex_replace:'/[^0-9\.]/':''}
```

This will remove anything that isn't a digit or period from the string.

Comment: i think this could help!!! I used it like:  ecomm_totalvalue: {/literal}{$PRODUCTS_PRICE|regex_replace:"/[^0-9\.]/":""}{literal};
but the result is 130000 now i need the dot

Comment: Use single quotes, sorry about that.  You may also add another backslash to ensure it works.

Comment: hi again. where are the comments? they are gone.

Comment: @tomseno1 - This should be pretty close, the adjustments you may need to make are to ensure the period is passed as is, not as a wildcard and the way to do that is to precede it with a backslash or two or even three.  Using single or double quotes may yield different results, you'll need to test them out to find the one that works best.